# How do I pull from another computer's repository in Git?

Tags: git, git-pull

For example, I have cloned the origin repository on two computers. Then, I go ahead and make some changes and commit to the local repository of computer A. How do I now pull these changes to computer B? Both computer A and B are connected to a network.

What I am looking for will be the equivalent of someone manually creating a patch and sending it to me, which I can apply to my working copy/local repo.

Comment: not really a local repository if it's on another computer, in my opinion: thus @Antoine's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4131211/155090) better matches your question's title …

Comment: … while @Amber's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4131239/155090) matches the clarifying details of your question's narrative.

Comment: I wish this question had a Windows answer

Answer (score 125, accepted):

If the machine you want to pull from is accessible via `ssh`, you can add the repository on it as a remote via ssh, and then pull from it like you would any remote:

```
$ git remote add repo_b username@host:path/to/repository.git
$ git pull repo_b master
```

(You can skip the step of adding a remote and just specify the full URL in the `git pull` command instead of a remote name, but if you're going to be pulling from the repository on a regular basis, adding it as a remote will save you lots of typing.)

Comment: And how about the push from computer_b? will computer_b push the changes as normal? "git push"?

Comment: For a local repo, you can use the same thing, but set up remote path as `file:///local/path/to/repo/.git/`

Comment: This does not work for me, the URL has to be `/path/to/repository/.git/`.

Comment: thank you, wasnt enough +1 this time, neat solution

Answer (score 37):

Have a look at `git pull --help`

This would give something like `git pull /my/other/repository`

Comment: Specifically, under the section *GIT URLS*, it says: "For local repositories, also supported by git natively, the following syntaxes may be used: `/path/to/repo.git/`, `file:///path/to/repo.git/`"

Answer (score 14):

You can set up an actual server with [git daemon](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html).  Otherwise, you can use [git bundle](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html), which bundles git's internal representation into a file that can be unbundled with `git pull` at the other end.

E.g. from the git docs, bundling everything:

```
git bundle create file.bundle master
```

Then, on the other end, you can do something like:

```
git pull file.bundle HEAD
```

Answer (score 8):

If you can connect to computer B by ssh, you can use:

```
git clone user@host:/path/to/repo
```

It will enable remote tracking through this ssh connection, and allow you to use git pull/push.

Comment: It helps me, but I need to enable the remote login before cloning.

Answer (score 4):

A bit too late, but for all it worth and to extend the Antoine Pelisse answer, you can also pull from ssh host that has the same repo with couple of more commits in it, without adding a **remote** to your config:

```
git pull user@host:/path/to/repo  # while in the local repo folder
```

Just to be clear - one of possible uses of this is when you have two hosts (A and B) that cloned the same repo from a **remote**, and you've committed some changes on host A and do not wish to push them to **remote** (yet), but instead want to pull those commits from host B. The command above with synchronise your repos without pushing to **remote**.

Comment: You can of course have multiple remotes.  So on host A, I would configure two remotes:  one called origin which is where you cloned from, and one called B which is the repo on host B

Comment: @MartinBonner I know you can which is clearly stated in the accepted answer. I'm merely stating that you do not have to. Looks like the accepted answer was updated to state the same since.

Comment: I find this actually incredibly useful

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me for a local repository with another computer:

```
git remote add origin_username username@10.0.0.2:/home/username/dev/project/main/.git/

git pull origin_username master
```

or

```
git pull origin_username some_branch
```

Comment: you can list all remote branch using: git ls-remote origin_username

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with

```
git clone /path/to/local/repository
```